# Python static method display issue

Tags: python-2.7

I've created a static method `display()` which should display its content before initializing the class object. However my insert function works first but I feel logically it should execute Queue.display first...

```
class Queue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        front = 0
        rear = -1
        list1 = []
        self.front = front
        self.rear = rear
        self.list1 = list1  
    def display(self):
        print "From Display()"
        print "Front stat :", self.front
        print "Rear Stat:", self.rear                    
        display = staticmethod(display)
    def insert(self,x):
         if len(self.list1) > 5:
            print "Queue max"
        else:        
            self.list1.append(x)
            print "Insertion"
            self.rear += 1
            print "list :", self.list1
            Queue.display(self)
    def remove(self, y):
        self.list1.remove(y)
        self.front += 1
        Queue.display(self)
#below command should
#execute first but doesn't 
Queue.display
q = Queue()
q.insert(100)
q.insert(200)
q.insert(300)
```

Comment: `display` **isn't** a static method. Not should it be, as it is accessing instance attributes. What exactly is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can not access an instance by using self, when you didn't instantiate the class. You can either have classmethods, accessing class instances, or static methods, accessing nothing of the class at all. What you probably want, in case you really want to display anything before instantiation, is something like that below.

front and rear are now class level attributes. You can access them from an instance, just like instance attributes. When you write to them, no harm is done, they're only overwritten for that instance, so they serve as kind of default values for the instance. Careful though, don't do that with list, as list is of mutable type, and all changes would end up there in the class attribute. Also note, to call a function, you need to add the brackets in the end (the tried call to Queue.display near the end).

```
class Queue(object):
    front = 0
    rear = -1

    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = []

    @classmethod
    def display_default(cls):
        print "From Display()"
        print "Front stat:", cls.front
        print "Rear stat:", cls.rear

    def display(self):
        print "Front stat:", self.front
        print "Rear stat:", self.rear

    def insert(self, x):
        if len(self.list1) > 5:
            print "Queue max"
        else:
            self.list1.append(x)
            print "Insertion"
            self.rear += 1
            print "list:", self.list1
            self.display()

    def remove(self, y):
        self.list1.remove(y)
        self.front += 1
        self.display()

Queue.display_default()

q = Queue()
q.insert(100)
q.insert(200)
q.insert(300)
```